# Сократить регулярное выражение в .htaccess

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Ребят, как можно упростить данное регулярное выражение? 2 строки как-то не круто. + я уверен, что есть способ нормальный.

```
RewriteRule ^tasks/?$ /modules/tasks/index.php
RewriteRule ^tasks/(.*?)/?$ /modules/tasks/$1.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае ваш подход является вполне нормальной практикой.